# Floating vote buttons (script)

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

## [Tampermonkey script that brings back an old Stack Exchange feature that never made it out of beta:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314017/296278)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sticky post vote buttons
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1
// @description  Sticky post vote buttons
// @author       RANDOM HOMO SAPIEN
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.votecell .vote').css({'position': 'sticky', 'top': '60px'});
})();
```

Comment: I found that this doesn't work (in some browsers at least) on the [elu.se] Stack Exchange because `overflow: auto;` has been set on `#content`, so in my local copy I've added `$('#content').css({'overflow': 'visible'});` to make it match the other sites. I also prefer having the vote buttons float down next to the comment section as well as the question/answer, so I added `$('.votecell').css({'grid-row': '1 / span 2'});` too.

Comment: This script isn't working properly for me any more. ☹

Comment: Just change the main query line to this `$('.js-voting-container').css({'position': 'sticky', 'top': '60px'});`